# DELL latitude D620, it won't start up until I warm the motherboard

Tags: google-chrome

I have a laptop DELL latitude D620, it won't start up until I warm the motherboard with blower just I want to remove capacitor then if I switch on it will start and I can keep it on as long as I wish but If I'll shut it down, It won't start up until I warm it again.
SO CAN ANY ONE TELL ME EXACTLY WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?

Comment: It sounds you may have a bad motherboard, but it's difficult to understand what you are describing. What do you mean "I want to remove capacitor"? How cold is the laptop before you warm it?